# How to get username by it's id in a view in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

Here is my code in which there is a key for user_id in the posts array but I want to show the username instead of it's id. Where can I write a function like findUserNameById($id) and call it in a view.

```
<table>
<tr><td>Sr. No.</td><td>User</td><td>Post</td></tr>
<?php
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($topic['Post'] as $post) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$counter."</td><td>".$post['user_id']."</td><td>".$post['body']."</td></tr>";
        $counter++;
    }
?>
</table>
```

here's my array:

```
Array
(
    [Topic] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 0
            [title] => Some title
            [visible] => 1
            [created] => 2014-09-20 02:03:42
            [modified] => 2014-09-20 22:30:45
        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [username] => 
            [password] => 
            [full_name] => 
            [role] => 
            [created] => 
            [modified] => 
        )

    [Post] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [topic_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 0
                    [body] => CakePHP 1
                    [created] => 2014-09-20 02:08:51
                    [modified] => 2014-09-20 02:08:51
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [topic_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 0
                    [body] => CakePHP 2
                    [created] => 2014-09-20 02:08:51
                    [modified] => 2014-09-20 02:08:51
                )

        )

)
```

There's key for the user for the topic but that is not available in case of posts but I have the id.

Answer (score 1):

You write a function like that in the User model (*i.e., following the fat model, skinny controller pattern*).

However, that is overkill since there is already a [field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field) method which should meet your needs.

Then you call your method in the controller, and send the data to the view via [set](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::set)